# Removing old Java installations on macOS

Tags: java, macos, system-administration

There are multiple Java virtual machine installations on my computer:

```
ls -la /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/                                                                          
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Oct  2 09:44 jdk-11.jdk/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Mar 11  2018 jdk1.8.0_131.jdk/
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel    96B Sep  4  2015 jdk1.8.0_60.jdk/
```

I don't really know/remember why they are here. https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/remove_olderversions.xml recommends uninstalling old Java. The method is some force rm commands. So I wonder how do I know if the seemingly old 'jdk1.8.0_60.jdk' is really safe to delete? The OS is macOS 10.14.1.

Comment: Java 8 really isn't that old and *might* still be in use.  Personally I'd leave it.

Comment: @markspace seeing as he has 2 Java 8 installations, removing the older one is prudent.